# как записать в файл введенный текст в поле и вывести его на экран PHP

Tags: php, input, текст

есть код с текстовым полем, и как нажать GO он выведет "Вы ввели: *text"

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="first" />
<input type="submit" name="ok_go" value="GO" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ok_go'])){
$first_var = $_POST['first'];
$first_var = trim($first_var);
if(empty($first_var)) echo 'Пусто';
else {
echo 'Вы ввели: <b>', $first_var, '</b>';
}
}
?>
```

как сделать чтобы если ввести в это поле любой текст, он записывался в файл и при заходе на эту страницу то появлялся текст из файла, ну и чтобы его можно было перезаписать.

Comment: Что значит - как сделать? Поискать в гугле - `php запись в файл`, `php чтение из файла` и сделать.

Comment: file_put_contents и file_get_contents

Comment: ну сказать легко, у меня просто не получается, просто Notice

Comment: И мы должны вероятно угадать какой код выводит Notice, да?

Answer (score 0):

Я так подозреваю вы это хотите сделать 
если да то советую ознакомиться  этой [статьёй https://metanit.com/web/php/5.1.php](https://metanit.com/web/php/5.1.php)

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="first" />
<input type="submit" name="ok_go" value="GO" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ok_go'])){
$first_var = $_POST['first'];
$first_var = trim($first_var);
if(empty($first_var)) echo 'Пусто';
else {
$fd = fopen("hello.txt", 'w') or die("не удалось создать файл");
$str = $first_var;
fwrite($fd, $str);
fclose($fd);
echo 'Вы ввели:';

$fd = fopen("hello.txt", 'r') or die("не удалось открыть файл");
while(!feof($fd))
{
    $str = htmlentities(fgets($fd));
    echo $str;
}
fclose($fd);
}
}
```